# Data-type as parameter

Tags: database, syntax, progress-4gl

I'd like to add a `data type` paramater to my application. This parameter would accept all primitive types and classes.

F.ex:

```
FUNCTION receiveDataType RETURNS LOGICAL (dataType AS DATATYPE):

    IF dataType = mypackage.MyClass THEN ...
    ELSE IF dataType = INTEGER THEN ...

END FUNCTION.
```

One way would be to use `CHARACTER`-parameter and validate that it refers to existing `data type`. However, some of Progress' own procedures take data types as parameters (f.ex `CAST()`). Is it possible to do the same with user created procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are strictly typed at compile time so you can't do it that way.

Procedures will auto-convert any type to the target input parameter type - if they can.

OO has overloading which means different methods can be created in a class with the data types you're looking for, and the code'll call the corresponding method when you compile / run it. You can then have your code call a common routine in the class to do what you want.

Comment: I'd like to add: to support any types of Progress parameters, you'd need make as many overloaded methods as there exists primitive types (Char, LongChar, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Int, Int64, Logical) and for classes (Progress.Lang.Object) as there is no 'common base class' for all types.